# Deleted Group in FreeIPA Still Comes Up

Tags: freeipa

I'm having an issue deleting a group in FreeIPA. A group was previously created called "developer" for which I want to delete.

I go into "User Groups" in FreeIPA GUI and delete the offending group name. All sounds good, but then if I go to my clients and do

```
getent group developer
```

I get

```
developer:*:[gid]:(members list)
```

In other words, the still comes up. I go into the individual group members and the group does not show in their account.

How do I permanently delete this key?

I'm running FreeIPA version 4.5.4 on CentOS 7

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the member server has cached the group. The caching is done by sssd, which also handles many other services related to the domain.

You can use the `sss_cache` tool to manage the cache. For example, to clear all group entries from the cache:

```
sss_cache -G
```

Comment: Awesome. That did it. Thank you very much!